# Evaluate function from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary which contains functions. For example:

```
def myfunction(parameter) = return "Function with parameter " % parameter
dictionary = {"myfunction" : myfunction}
```

Now I want to call this function with parameter, for example if input looks like:

```
myfunction some string
```

The first word is key to dictionary and other words are parameters of this function (or one parameter which contains a string).

Is it posible to use `eval()`? And how can I pass the parameters to my function?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you are inventing new syntax?

Comment: This is perfectly valid syntax in PyRubyScriptSh. :)

Comment: Anyway, `eval` will not help you here, because you have actual functions, not strings that can be evaluated into function expressions. But that's a good thing, not a problem. If `eval` helps, you're usually doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic example:

```
>>> def hello(name='World'): print('Hello %s' % name)

>>> hello()
Hello World

>>> hello('Vist')
Hello Vist

>>> d = {'fun': hello}

>>> d['fun']()
Hello World

>>> d['fun']('Vist')
Hello Vist
```

Example with variable number of arguments:

```
>>> def hello(*args): print('Hello %s' % ', '.join(args))

>>> hello()
Hello

>>> hello('Anna')
Hello Anna

>>> hello('Anna', 'Bob')
Hello Anna, Bob

>>> hello('Anna', 'Bob', 'Clara')
Hello Anna, Bob, Clara

>>> s = 'hello Diane Eric'

>>> d = {'hello': hello}

>>> d[s.split()[0]](*s.split()[1:])
Hello Diane, Eric
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split your input string, and use the first chunk to look up the function in the dictionary. Then pass the remaining chunks to the function.

```
s = 'myfunction some string'
chunks = s.split()

func = dictionary.get(chunks[0])

if not func:
    print 'Not found'
    return

func(chunks[1:])
```